# How to create an object with properties in the resolve parameter in the route provider in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to pre-load data in my controller. I am doing this using `resolve` in the routeprovider:

```
.when('/customers', {
    controller: 'CustomerController', templateUrl: '/Customer/Index', resolve: {
        countries: CustomerController.loadCountries,
        genders: CustomerController.loadGenders,
    }
})
```

As you can see I have two objects which will be injected into my controller, countries and gender. All this works fine.

What I want to do is, I want those objects to be part of one object: listData. I've tried:

```
.when('/customers', {
    controller: 'CustomerController', templateUrl: '/Customer/Index', resolve: {
        listData: {
            countries: CustomerController.loadCountries,
            genders: CustomerController.loadGenders
        }
    }
})
```

but this doesn't work: `Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object`.

What is the right syntax / approach to accomplish this?

Comment: if you want to use this approach then you have either to define controller globally without module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass an object to a key, you must have a function as the value :

```
listData: function () {
  // you need to inject 
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var listData = {};
  // these should be services, btw !
  CustomerController.loadCountries.then(function (countries) {
    listData.countries = countries;
    // resolve when you have both
    if (listData.genders) deferred.resolve(listData);
  });
  CustomerController.loadGenders.then(function (genders) {
    listData.genders = genders;
    if (listData.countries) deferred.resolve(listData);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: This is exaclty what I want and fyi, I do have services :)

Comment: I don't know, "CustomerController.loadGenders" doesn't seem that service-y to me, but whaveter :).